# com.google.gms.location does not exist

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to add a map on the `Xamarin.Android` application. So far, I have added only map, I did not add any location listener. However, I keep getting the following error

> package,`com.google.gms.location` does not exist

I wonder what I am missing or doing wrong?

Here is the dll's added into the references from the nuget

[image]

[image]

Comment: how you "added only map"? Nuget? Which one?

Comment: I have added version 27.0.0, `Maps, Base, Basement and Location`

Comment: What is the Nuget package name. For example: Crosslight.Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location or Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location. Check this link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69174/map-where-i-can-find-this-android-gms-location-locationservices-api

Comment: I used `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location`

Comment: then it should be version 42 not 27.

Comment: Why it should be 42? I chose 27, because it is stable and does not need to update existing dlls. and it is not too old, it just 1-2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure all packages are of the same version (27.0.0)
2. Make sure Xamarin.Build.Download is installed (it downloads the required .jar files etc.)
3. Clean & Rebuild the android Project
4. Try entering `Update-Package -Reinstall Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location`into the package manager console
5. Clean & Rebuild the android Project
6. Try a higher version number of the package (newer ones are stable too)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use GooglePlayService. The test device/emulator of your app needs to include Google API. If you are using an emulator you can follow the steps below:

1. Download Google API System Image for your android API Level through `Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager`(ex for API Level 25 ):
   [image]
2. Create a new Google API Emulator through `Tools->Android->Android Emulator Manager->Create`:

[image]

3. Clean your project and rebuild it, run your project in this emulator.